# Pandas Dataframe: Remove duplicate rows and append data to remaining unique row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following structure of the df (as an example):

*Edited data based on comment*

```
import pandas as pd
    
    
data = {'ID':["abc", "abc", "123", "xyz", "xyz"], 'valid':[["A", "B"], [], [], ["A", "B", "C"], []],
        'not_valid':[[], ["C", "D"], ["A", "B", "C", "D"], [], ["D"]],
       'other_data': ["1", "1", "3", "4", "4"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Which gives:

```
ID    valid         not_valid      other_data
abc   [A, B]        []             1
abc   []            [C, D]         1
123   []            [A, B, C, D]   3
xyz   [A, B, C]     []             4
xyz   []            [D]            4
```

What I want as a result is the following:

```
ID    valid         not_valid      other_data
abc   [A, B]        [C, D]         1
123   []            [A, B, C, D]   3
xyz   [A, B, C]     [D]            4
```

I was wondering how I can merge the two columns `valid` and `not_valid` for each unique ID together (not every ID has necessarily two entries like in this case `123`).

While I can remove duplicates with

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID']).reset_index()
```

I obviously loose half of the data for duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flatten values with convert values to sets and then to lists in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
cols = ['valid','not_valid']
df = df.groupby('ID', sort=False)[cols].agg(lambda x: list(set(z for y in x for z in y)))
print (df)
         valid     not_valid
ID                          
abc     [A, B]        [D, C]
123         []  [A, D, B, C]
xyz  [A, B, C]           [D]
```

EDIT: If all values of another columns are same per groups by `ID` use:

```
#grouping by all columns without valid, not_valid
c = df.columns.difference(['valid','not_valid']).tolist()
f = lambda x: list(set(z for y in x for z in y))
df1 = df.groupby(c, sort=False, as_index=False).agg(f).reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df1)
    ID      valid     not_valid other_data
0  abc     [A, B]        [D, C]          1
1  123         []  [A, D, B, C]          3
2  xyz  [A, B, C]           [D]          4
```

Comment: you are rock !1

Comment: Thank you! How can I alter this code that it only checks for the two valid columns? In case there are additional colums in the df.

Comment: @Colle - If there is more columns, is possible change data sample with expected output - e.g if 2 new columns?

Comment: @jezrael I edited the OP. Basically, for all duplicate IDs, all columns values would be the same expect the "valid" and "not_valid" columns.

Comment: @Colle - yop, so you can pass all columns to groupby like `df = df.groupby(['ID','other_data'], sort=False).agg(lambda x: list(set(z for y in x for z in y)))` ?

Comment: @Colle - because same values per groups like `ID` ?